# PostgreSQL timezone error with DbSchema

Tags: postgresql, timezone, synology, db-schema

I want to setup my postgreSQL server to `'Europe/Berlin'` but having an error:

```
SET time zone 'Europe/Berlin';
ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
```

But the real issue is with DdbSchema, when I want to connect to my DB i've got the error

```
FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
```

DbSchema works when I connect to my local db but not with my NAS (Synology) DB.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to solve the problem:

You have to start java with the proper time zone.

In my case, my server is GMT, so i had to add the args `-Duser.timezone=GMT`

- For DbSchema, edit the file `DbSchema.bat` or `DbSchema.sh`
- Find the declaration of `SWING_JVM_ARGS`
- Add the argument `-Duser.timezone=GMT` a the end of the line
- Start DbSchema with this script `DbSchema.bat` or `DbSchema.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is only a workaround for the actual problem concerning the zoneinfo on the synology diskstation.

I got exactly the same error when trying to connect to the postgres database on my diskstation. The query `select * from pg_timezone_names;` gives you all timezone names postgresql is aware of.

There are 87 entries all starting with "Timezone":

```
          name          | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
------------------------+--------+------------+--------
 Timezone/Kuwait        | AST    | 03:00:00   | f
 Timezone/Nairobi       | EAT    | 03:00:00   | f
 ...
```

The configured postgres `timezonesets` contain much more entries, so there must be another source that postgres is building this view of at startup. I discovered that there is a compile-option `--with-system-tzdata=DIRECTORY` that tells postgres to obtain its values from system zoneinfo.

I looked in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` and found one subdirectory called `Timezone` with exactly 87 entries. And there obviously was no subdirectory called `Europe` (with a timezone file called `Berlin`). I did not quickly find a solution for the diskstation to update the `tzdata` automatically or manually by unpacking `tzdata2016a.tar.gz` and making (`make not found`...). As a quickfix I copied the `Berlin` timezone file from another linux system and the problem was solved, so that I now can connect via java/jdbc using the correct timezone "Europe/Berlin"!